# Is there any example of Spring Schedule that reads Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-scheduled

We're trying to read the data from Kafka at specified window time (so we have Kafka consumer), that means avoiding the data read at other times.  However we're not sure how to shut down the consumer after the time period is expired.  I wonder if there are any example of how to do that?  Many thanks in advance for helping us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable the `autoStartup` and then manually start the kafka `containers` using [KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.html) `start` and `stop` methods
[@KafkaListener Lifecycle Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle)

```
public class KafkaConsumer {

 @Autowired
 private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

  @KafkaListener(id = "myContainer", topics = "myTopic", autoStartup = "false")
  public void listen(...) { ... }

  @Schedule(cron = "")
  public void scheduledMethod() {

   registry.start();

   registry.stop()
  }
```

But in the above approach there is no guarantee that all messages from kafka will be consumed in that time frame (It depends on load and processing speed)

Comment: this seems to work but for me I also have other KafkaListeners without autoStartup set to false. When registry.stop() is called those KafkaListeners are also stopped, is there a way to work around this?

Comment: In fact I think i can manage each container from registry.
See here https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

I had the same use case but I wrote the scheduler specifying the max poll record for one batch and kept a counter if the counter matched the max polled record then I consider that the processing for the batch is finished as it has processed the record which it got during the one poll.

And then I am unsubscribing to the topic and closing the consumer. The next time when the scheduler will run it will again process the max poll record specified limit.

fixedDelayString fulfil the purpose that the scheduler starts after the specified time limit once the previous is finished.

```
@EnableScheduling
public class MessageScheduler{

        @Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${fixedInitialDelay.in.milliseconds}", fixedDelayString = "${fixedDelay.in.milliseconds}")
        public void run(){

            /*write your kafka consumer here with manual commit*/

            /*once your batch is finished processing unsubcribe and close the consumer*/
                kafkaConsumer.unsubscribe();
                kafkaConsumer.close();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question `Kafka spring boot listener read messages in time interval` was marked as duplicated of this, but i think it has a differente response.

In order to change the default (0ms) interval Spring polls messages you can set a new idleBetweenPolls when the containerFactory bean is created

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaEventListenerObjectContainerFactory(){
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory()
    factory.containerProperties.setIdleBetweenPolls(500L); // new interval in milisecons
        ...
    return factory;
}
```