# Kafka spring boot listener read messages in time interval

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

i'm working in spring boot project as a kafka consumer , i'm consuming kafka messages using spring listener but my listener read all messages (hundred in second) and i want to control the messages consumption like consuming only one message after each 5min.
this is my code :

```java
private final CountDownLatch latch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
@KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topics.topicName}",  containerFactory = "kafkaEventListenerObjectContainerFactory")
    
public void listenTopicInfo(ConsumerRecord<String, KafkaEvent> cr, @Payload KafkaEvent kafkaEvent) {
    LOG.info("New kafka event arrived {} from topic {}", kafkaEvent.getId(),"topicName");
    this.latch1.countDown();  
}
```

do you have any idea please how i can do that ?

Regards.

Comment: You could always consume the data into in-memory batches, *then* schedule processing on them, which is similar to the Kafka Streams punctuation https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/kafka-streams-schedule-operations/kstreams.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you for your respone. but the tutorial is not clear it talk about kafka producer..

Comment: Only to get data originally into a brand new topic. Scroll down to the Punctuator usage

Comment: i think this question is not duplicated, i answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260089/is-there-any-example-of-spring-schedule-that-reads-kafka-topic/75779583#75779583